# What is the difference between Form1.Hide() and Form1.Visible = false?

Tags: c#, winforms, hide, visible

I'm going to write a function using one of two above command, but I don't know which I should use.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no real difference.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx)

> Hiding the control is **equivalent to setting the Visible property to
>   false**. After the Hide method is called, the Visible property returns a
>   value of false until the Show method is called.